# How to print dictionary keys and values?

Tags: python, dictionary, tabular

I have a dictionary, and I want to print it in a table.

Example:

Dictionary:

```
{'Color1': 'Red', 'Color2': 'Blue', 'Color3': 'Yellow', 'Color4': 'Green'}
```

And I want a table like:

```
NUMBER:         COLOR:
Color1          Red
Color2          Blue
Color3          Yellow
Color4          Green
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
d={'Color1': 'Red', 'Color2': 'Blue', 'Color3': 'Yellow', 'Color4': 'Green'}

print ("{:<12} {:<12} ".format('NUMBER:','COLOR:'))
for i in range(5):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k[5] == str(i):
            print("{:<12} {:<12}".format(k, v))
```

you can get with this in order.

Output is;

```
NUMBER:      COLOR:       
Color1       Red         
Color2       Blue        
Color3       Yellow      
Color4       Green
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = {'Color1': 'Red', 'Color2': 'Blue', 'Color3': 'Yellow', 'Color4': 'Green'}
print "NUMBER    COLOR".format(k, v)
for k, v in colors.iteritems():
    print "{}    {}".format(k, v)
```

Comment: You don't need `format()` for the `"NUMBER    COLOR"` string. In fact, it'd throw a NameError if `k` or `v` haven't been defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to do that :D

```
colors={'Color1': 'Red', 'Color2': 'Blue', 'Color3': 'Yellow', 'Color4': 'Green'}
for k in colors.keys():
      print k + ":" + colors[k]
```